# New Entry in TNSNAMES.ora not identified

Tags: oracle, database-administration

I added a new connection in the tnsnames.ora on the server but I am getting the error below

```
tns could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

Does anyone have any idea on what can be the issue. I have not restarted the server after updating tnsnames.ora
The old connections are still working but not the new one.

Comment: Is this to support a database link? Or is this for a connection from a network client?

Comment: Use `strace` like this: `strace tnsping NEW_ALIAS`. it will at least tell you whether your file is parsed. If tnsping opens and reads your file, there is something wrong with its syntax.

Comment: You said tnsnames.ora was changed on your server, but tnsnames.ora is a *client* configuration file. If you update it on your server it will only impact use of sqlplus or other clients running on the same server, from that ORACLE_HOME, or DB link connections initiated from the server. If you want to provide new connection info for an application server or a desktop app on a different host, there is no built-in central management of tnsnames info; you will most likely need to update every tnsnames.ora on every network client separately. Where are you connecting from?

Comment: I guess I should also ask is this the database server that you updated, or an application server?